# Problem getting device location - flutter app

Tags: flutter, location, flutter-test, flutter-apk

I have programmed a weather app using flutter. It works perfectly on the virtual phone. But when i install it in my android phone. The app cant get the current location.

I used geolocator 6.0.0 package.

I also typed the permission code to ask for permission location in
AndroidManifest. xml

---

I tried to use my personal android phone and debug the app. The app worked fine.

So i get the problem when i run it as apk app. But it works fine when i debug it from visual code

Comment: Thank you. I just solved the problem by typing all android permissions in AndroidManifest. xml

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try another package - this one:
https://pub.dev/packages/location

it can also ask the user for permission to use location service (there's an example in the readme).